# How to create a RSS feed of certain content type ( without affecting the front end layout )?

Tags: 7, nodes, feeds

I would like to create a RSS feed of certain content type ( without affecting the front end layout ), but I am not quite sure how can I add this feature to Drupal. Any clues for me to start with?

p.s. I'm using Drupal 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Views will allow you to do it.  But when you make changes to the view you must select "over ride for this view" or it will change all views associated with the RSS feed.

Comment: Can you illustrate the settings? There are a lot of settings in Views, and I am confused.

Comment: Views deploys a type of cascading that can make it hard.  That was spoken in my answer.  I'd recommend you take a long time studding all the sections and its options.  The way you select a RSS feed is a pretty standard setting in the left section of it (if I remember correctly).  Unfortunately, I can not assist with images as I don't tend to work with Drupal much lately. When you change it, the above becomes important.  Do not change all your views to RSS feeds.